# How to turn off super dev mode in GWT?

Tags: maven, gwt, netbeans, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am using netbeans, for build I am using Maven. There is a flag -nosuperDevMode used to set super dev mode off, but i don't know where and how to use this in netbeans and maven.

How to turn off the super dev mode?

Also how to access GWT properties in netbeans like we can see and change them in eclipse?

I am using GWT 2.7

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
<superDevMode>false</superDevMode>
```

to your `gwt-maven-plugin` configuration, or pass `-Dgwt.superDevMode=false` on the command-line (or the equivalent when launching Maven from NetBeans).
See https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#superDevMode

Answer (score 1):

By default super dev mode is disabled. Starting with GWT 2.7, Dev Mode launches Super Dev Mode automatically.

Comment: and there is any way to disable super dev mode in GWT 2.7?

Comment: Did you try adding -nosuperDevMode to program arguments?

Comment: Can you tell me where to put that in netbeans? screenshot is preferable.

Comment: I do not use netbeans. How do you create debug/run configuration? Do you see the arguments tab in the configuration window?

Comment: I run it as maven goal i.e. gwt:run and it has parameters field but it is not taking it from there

Comment: You can create debug configuration in pom.  Here is the link https://javaworkshop.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/debugging-gwt-project-using-netbeans-and-maven-without-the-damn-plugins/   It shows how to pass arguments while debugging. Please look at the debug-gwt profile.